# Command equivalent to triggering "always on top"

Tags: window

I'm on Ubuntu 17.10 with Gnome and trying to figure out the command line equivalent to trigger "always on top". Note: as per my understanding in Wayland, wctrl won't work. :(

Long version: I very much prefer leveraging MPV for most of my online video viewing. Reason being, MPV does excellent hardware acceleration with vaapi on my 7th gen Intel. Catch is, the act of getting MPV to launch to a URL is irritating. I can either open the window, manually set it to always-on-top, drag/drop, profit -- or I can manuver my windows so I can see MPV without my browser covering it, drag and drop URL, profit -- or I can launch it in terminal and run mpv pastedURLhere. Instead I have my mpv.conf set to open in a small geometry. This allows plenty of room for me to drag/drop the URL, but the window of course disappears by default once I activate my browser, requiring me to set always-on-top each time. Yes - MPV has an option to add in mpv.conf to always open on top, but it doesn't seem to work in Wayland. Thus, I'm trying to figure out the exact command to trigger this in an effort to make a custom desktop launcher. That way I can open MPV exactly how I want it with plenty of room to drag/drop URLs and simply double click it to fullscreen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you had any success with this? I also would like to do this on weston/wayland for my project using console commands. Appreciated if you could share with me. @JaSauders